# warning C4552: '>>': result of expression not used

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int manic;

    std::cout << "Enter Size of Array" << "/n";
    std::cin >> size; // << "/n";
    size = manic;
    static const int arr[size];
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        std::cout << "Enter" << i << "Element" << "/n";
        std::cin >> (arr[i]); // Error Is Shown in this Line
    }
    bool r = is_even(arr, size);
    std::cout << r;
    return 0;
}
```

My first post here .I typed this code in Visual Studio 2019.The Microsfot Documents do not help.

Comment: Are you trying to write into const array?

Comment: You should post a [minimal reproducilbe example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), take a few minutes to read  the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of the site.

Comment: Where is `size` declared? [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62677747/edit) the question and add that.

Comment: Are you sure the error is on the line you've indicated, or is it somewhere else?

Comment: `static const int arr[size];` is a VLA and those are not included in the C++ standard - only as an extension in some compilers.

Comment: @Equod, yes, looks like it, but first some magic would be needed to be able to declare it like that.

Comment: If the error is where indicated it is because the array is constant. But there are other errors too such as size and is_even are undeclared.

Comment: Unrelated: `"/n"` prints `/n` not a newline. You want `"\n"` or, even better, `'\n'`.

Comment: You have many problems in your code. The warning is currently negligible. You are reading into `size` but `size` isn't declared. You are assigning the value of `manic` to `size` but `manic` is unitialized. You are trying to create a variable-length array with MSVC. Why is this array static? You are creating a `const` array but you don't initalize it. You are trying to write into a `const` array. You are calling `is_even` but it's not defined.

Comment: _"Why is this array static? You are creating a const array but you don't initalize it."_ That's not correct. Since it's static it is initialized with zeros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler gives you the hint that you may uninentionally override a value

```
std::cin >> size;// << "/n";
size = manic;
```

You let the user input a value and then override it with another, by the way uninitialized, value.

Comment: The warning comes from this line: `std::cin >> (arr[i]);`